# AES/GCM/NoPadding decryption need TAG How to find Tag while encryption

Tags: android, node.js, caesar-cipher, aes-gcm

Here is my encryption method also Decryption method its working fine with Tag Basically server need TAG is it possible server find Tag by my Hex String because every String i send Tag to the server and also with Hex, is it have any other optimal solution

```
aesKey=context.getString(R.string.aes_key).getBytes();
iv=context.getString(R.string.input_vector).getBytes();


public Map encrypt(String string){
    byte[] plainText= new byte[0];
    try {
        plainText = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Cipher cipher = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] cipherText = new byte[0];
    byte[] tag = new byte[0];
    try {

        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
        tag= Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherText, cipherText.length -16, cipherText.length);
        cipherText= Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherText, 0, cipherText.length -16);

        Log.d("testing", "encrypt: "+byteArrayToHexString(tag));
        Map<String, Object> map=new HashMap();
        map.put("content",byteArrayToHexString(cipherText));
        map.put("tag",tag);
        Log.d("testing", "encrypt: "+new Gson().toJson(map));
        return map;
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new HashMap();
}
```

Server need Hex so i convert it into Hex

```
public  String byteArrayToHexString(final byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(byte b : bytes){
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b&0xff));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

My Decryption Function is that return me the String i receive Tag and Hex String from the server

```
    public String decrypt(String content,byte[] tag){


    byte[] cipherText = hexStringToByteArray(content+byteArrayToHexString(tag));


    Cipher cipher = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] plainText = new byte[0];
    try {
        plainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Log.d("testing", "encrypt: plain text:"+new String(plainText,"UTF-8"));
        return new String(plainText,"UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if this code is really executed in your environment. On my machine an `InvalidAlgorithmParameterException` (_Unsupported parameter: javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec_) is thrown, because for GCM a `GCMParameterSpec` is actually to be used instead of an `IvParameterSpec`. When this issue is fixed, encryption succeeds.

Comment: The problem with the decryption is probably due to either a bug in the decryption code or an incompatibility between decryption and encryption. For further analysis post the decryption code please.

Comment: Btw, the posted decrypted plaintext is not very helpful without knowing the original plaintext. So kindly post a complete set of _test_ data: plaintext, key, IV, ciphertext (e.g. Base64 encoded), decrypted text (preferably Base64 encoded).

Comment: In Java, the tag is appended to the ciphertext at byte level without separator (ciphertext | tag). Whether the server expects ciphertext and tag concatenated or both separated depends on the implementation used by the server.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks, is TAG size is always 16 bytes? basically is get TAG like this

tag= Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherText, cipherText.length -16, cipherText.length);
            cipherText= Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherText, 0, cipherText.length -16);

and then send text and TAG separate to the server

is it possible server find TAG from my HEX string?

Comment: @Topaco i also update my question Please review it

Comment: @Topaco What is the optimal way to get find TAG?
or i am working fine to get TAG

Comment: Which Java version and which environment do you use? I'm not sure why you can run `AES/GCM/NoPadding` in combination with `IvParameterSpec`. Actually GCM needs `GCMParameterSpec`, which allows to specify the tag length explicitly.  The tag is usually 16 bytes long for GCM, and the IV is 12 bytes long. The code posted in the comment separates a 16 bytes tag from the ciphertext.

Comment: I am using java 8 in android studio. Ok i will specify the TAG length my question is, Is it have any function to get TAG?

Comment: @Topaco in Android is it have any other way or function to get TAG?

Comment: Is it have any possible way, if i am not send the Tag to the server and server decrypt my string?

Comment: @Topaco I am using java 8 in android studio. Ok i will specify the TAG length my question is, Is it have any function to get TAG or i cut 16 bytes from the end every time?
Is it have any possible way, if i am not send the Tag to the server and Node server decrypt my string?

Comment: OK for the Android API apparently `AES/GCM/NoPadding` also works in combination with `IvParameterSpec`, the generated tag is 16 bytes long. So `GCMParameterSpec` does not have to be used _mandatory_ here. This does not work in the Java API, here `GCMParameterSpec` must be used. FYI: The tag length (no matter if `IvParameterSpec` or `GCMParameterSpec` was used) can be determined with `cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(GCMParameterSpec.class).getTLen()`.

Comment: To your questions: _in Android is it have any other way or function to get TAG?_ To my knowledge, no (i.e. you always have to separate).

Comment: _Is it have any possible way, if i am not send the Tag to the server and Node server decrypt my string?_ You haven't posted anything about the GCM implementation of the NodeJS site, so I can only answer in general terms: The benefit of GCM is the tag, i.e. the authentication. GCM without authentication makes little sense, then you can also use a mode without authentication. In principle, however, with a 12 bytes IV for GCM a decryption without tag is possible, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/57905). But this must be implemented (i.e. it does not work like this by default).